# Not able to update the page if the user is logged in or not. FlutterFire

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was doing a project and I encounter a problem. I want the app changes page if the user is logged in or not even if it's starting the app. I came up with an idea to have a widget under the root called Wrapper that has a function to change each time the authentication state changes.
But it doesn't work...
Could you guys help me with that?

The Wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(updateUserStatus())
      return Home();
    else
      return Authenticate();
  }
  

  bool updateUserStatus() {
    bool isLogged = false;
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        isLogged = false;
        print("User Not logged");
      } else {
        isLogged = true;
        print("User logged");
      }
    });
    return isLogged;
  }
  }
```

The output on the Debug console is right but, the page doesn't change.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, brother for not answering  in details. But I had encountered the same problem, to solve this issue I watched the following playlist in youtube, it gives solution to your problem, but you have to watch it till the end.This is a link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Lyx8KJWpg&list=PLNnAcB93JKV_NIGSneTazb9yMpILapEjo